# Wordpress rss-feed is not showing ful text of a post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, rss2

I have built a custom theme using understarp theme and I am unable to see summary or full text of my post in my RSS-feed. it starts showing text only when I add something in the excerpt field and still it shows only the content of excerpt field.

is it possible to show the full text of a post in RSS feed or no?

Comment: It is possible. You should check the options under Settings->Reading? - But, if it doesn't display anything you should check functions that truncate or modify the excerpt.

Comment: @KevinMamaqi thanks for your response. sorry, I forgot to comment before that but I have figured it out. It took me a little long but that's ok.
problem was, we were adding some ads HTML in the content of my posts using "the_content" filter and we were returning the updated content only in an "if" statement. I noticed there was no return statement for "else" so that's why it was giving me empty content.

Answer (score 0):

problem was, we were adding some ads HTML in the content of my posts using "the_content" filter and we were returning the updated content only in an "if" statement. I noticed there was no return statement for "else" so that's why it was giving me empty content